# getting error by using outer functions in multiple classes

Tags: c++, oop

I have 3 classes each class relate to other and 3 of them using the same functions, so I decide to create functions.h file that I will put the "outer" functions that everyone use.
so for the demonstration:

```
functions.h
 len function
 subs function
A.cpp
  #include "functions.h"
  #include "A.h"
  #include "B.h"
  cout<<len(word);
B.cpp
   #include "functions.h"
   #include "B.h"
   #include "A.h"
   cout<<subs(word,0,1);
C.cpp
   cout<<len(word);
```

all of them include functions.h file with the specific functions, for the headers files I`m using header guard.
when I build the project I get the error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: "int __cdecl len(char *)" (?len@@YAHPAD@Z) already defined in A.obj  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\1033\Ass3\Ass3\B.obj Ass3
```

the same error is to subs(function).
any suggestions why its happen?
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
functions.h

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H
#include <math.h>

  int len(char *w){
     int count=0;
    int i=0;
  while (w[i]!='\0')
      {
          count++;
          i++;
      }
 //cout<<"Length of word is:"<<count<<"\n";
  return count;

}
  char *subs(char *w,int s,int e){
    int i,j=0;
    int size=0;

     size=abs((e))+1;
     //cout<<"new size is:"<<size<<"\n";
     char *newW=new char[size];


     for(i = 0 ;i<e; i++)
        {

           newW[i]=w[s];
           s++;

        }

    newW[i]='\0';
    return newW;

   }

   #endif
```

Word.cpp

```
#include "Word.h"
#include "functions.h"

Word::Word(char *_word){word=_word;}
bool Word::equals(char* _word){
    cout<<"len of the first word is: "<<len(word)<<" and len of the checked word is: "<<len(_word)<<endl;
    if(len(word)!=len(_word))
        return false;
    else{
    for(int i=0;i<len(word);i++)
        if(word[i]!=_word[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;

}
char Word::getWord(){
    char *nW = new char[len(word)];
    //cout<<"len of word is:"<<len(word);
    int l=len(word);
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            nW[i]=word[i];
            cout<<nW[i];
    }

    return *nW;

}
void Word::print(char *word){cout<<word;}
void Word::print(){cout<<word<<" ";}
```

Sentence.cpp

```
#include "Sentence.h"
#include "Word.h"
#include "functions.h"
Sentence::Sentence()
{

    char* sentence=new char[300];
    cout<<"Entere sentence"<<endl;
    cin.getline(sentence,300);
    int i,j=0,lastIndex=0,count=0;


    int l=len(sentence);
    cout<<"Size of sentence is: "<<l<<"\n";

    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
        //' ' ,'.', ',', '?', ':', '!' ,'\N','\r' ',', '\t', ',', '-'
        if (sentence[i]==' '||
            sentence[i]=='.'||
            sentence[i]==','||
            sentence[i]=='?'||
            sentence[i]==':'||
            sentence[i]=='!'||
            sentence[i]==';'||

            sentence[i]=='-'){
            count++;
            if(count==1)
                {
                    //cout<<subs(sentence,0,i);
                //cout<<"Start Index: 0 and Length is: "<<i<<"\n";
                words[j]=new Word(subs(sentence,0,i));



                    lastIndex=i;

                    j++;
                }
            else{


        //cout<<subs(sentence,lastIndex+1,i-lastIndex-1);
                //cout<<"Start Index: "<<lastIndex+1<<" and Length is: "<<i-lastIndex-1<<"\n";
            words[j]=new Word(subs(sentence,lastIndex+1,i-lastIndex-1));

            lastIndex=i;
            j++;
            }
        }

    }


    if(lastIndex==0){
        //cout<<subs(sentence,0,l);

        words[j]= new Word(subs(sentence,0,l));
    }
    else{
        //cout<<subs(sentence,lastIndex+1,i);
        //cout<<"Start Index: "<<lastIndex+1<<" and length is: "<<i-lastIndex-1<<"\n";
        words[j]= new Word(subs(sentence,lastIndex+1,i-lastIndex-1));

    }
    wordNum=count+1;

}
bool Sentence::containsWord(char* _word){

    for(int i=0;i<200;i++){


        if(words[i]->equals(_word))
                return true;

    }
    return false;

}

int Sentence::getWordNum(char *_word){

    for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
        cout<<words[i]->getWord();
        if(words[i]->equals(_word))
                return i+1;

    }
    return -1;

}
int Sentence::getWords(){return wordNum;}
int Word::getLen(){

    return len(word);
}
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal example with real code?

Comment: why are you defining Word::getLen() in Sentence.cpp?

Comment: Nice and **minimal**.

Comment: @StefanoFalasca I just wrote it for now, I will delete it, this is not the point of my question. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you've put functions *implementations* into `functions.h`. Leave *prototypes* there and move *implementations* to separate file, like `functions.cpp`.

This should do the trick.

**Update** a bit more explanation of the error you've got.

When you use `#include` it will be processed by processor before compilation (think of it like inlining `.h` file into source file). This process occurs for every compilation unit, i'e `.cpp` file (think of it like root of a tree).

Now, since "roots" of the include trees are different (`A.cpp`, `B.cpp`, ...) include guard won't help you to avoid **function implementations** from being inlined into every compilation unit.

This will cause link errors since, well, there is more than one implementation of those functions.

Comment: Ok, got it, the main problem were in my implementation of functions.h I didnt do that, so when I`m coding oop program I need to do that, in functional programing the error will not apear.

Comment: @OfirAttia It's not really about OOP vs functional. This is rather related to C/C++ and steps that are involved into build process. For example Java is OOP-oriented but there is no such problems there.

Comment: the problem shows in C as well. See my answer for a complete expanation of the problem. Of course it is no related with OOP/functional programming (in the C acception)

Answer (score 2):

Each compilation unit (namely A.cpp, B.cpp and C.cpp) have a definition of each of the functions contained in `functions.h`.

Include guards do not help with this, since they only happen to have an effect within the compilation unit boundaries (i.e. if you include, either directly or indirectly, `functions.h` twice in, say, A.cpp)

The possible solutions are:

1. you declare the functions in `functions.h`, and define them in a separate compilation unit, say `functions.cpp` (this is the way to go in your example)
2. you make each and every function in `functions.h` a template function (only do this if it makes sense)
3. you declare each and every function in `functions.h` to be static (this is only a workaround, I'm by no means suggesting you to do so!!!)

P.S. about point 3. It could be the case for this to make sense, so you probably want to know what is `static` about. When referred to a free function, the `static` keyword marks this function as local to the compilation unit. Hence, the function will not be exported in the linking table and will not be available to be called from within another compilation unit. This is why the "trick" works, alghought you still have multiple definitions, they are all "private" to each compilation unit, and there is no possible conflict. This is expecially useful when you use free-functions which are not part of an "interface" and are only meant to be local helper functions.